# How to use constructor in enum?

Tags: java, constructor, enums, singleton

I want to use an enum to create a singleton class in java. Should look like this:

```
public enum mySingleton implements myInterface {

    INSTANCE;
    private final myObject myString;

    private mySingleton(myObject myString) {
        this.myString= myString;
    }
}
```

Looks like I cannot use any parameters in the constructor. Is there any workaround for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Okay, I see that works. What if I have a more complex Object? I just edit the question..

Answer (score 3):

Yor enum is wrong. Below correct declaration:

```
public class Hello { 
    public enum MyEnum { 
            ONE("One value"), TWO("Two value"); //Here elements of enum.
            private String value; 
            private MyEnum(String value) { 
                this.value = value;
                System.out.println(this.value);  
            } 
            public String getValue() { 
                return value; 
            } 
    }
public static void main(String[] args) { 
        MyEnum e = MyEnum.ONE; 
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
One value
Two value
```

Conctructor is invoked for each element of enum.

Comment: I edited my question. It is not a String I have, but a more complex Object. I want to save a reference to this.

Comment: @KrawallKurt You may use any object as constructor arg. However, it must be statically known at compile time, so - depending on your use case - an enum might not be the right choice.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I just tried it with another enum. How would I do this? Like INSTANCE(myEnum); ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
enum Car {
   lamborghini(900),tata(2),audi(50),fiat(15),honda(12);
   private int price;
   Car(int p) {
      price = p;
   }
   int getPrice() {
      return price;
   } 
}
public class Main {
   public static void main(String args[]){
      System.out.println("All car prices:");
      for (Car c : Car.values())
      System.out.println(c + " costs " 
      + c.getPrice() + " thousand dollars.");
   }
}
```

Also see [more demos](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)